# At what exact time Netflix IPO started trading for public?

Tags: stock-analysis

At what exact time Netflix IPO started trading for public?
Need the exact time when the shares started trading.

Comment: https://www.cnbc.com/2019/02/01/netflixs-ipo-in-2002-watch-cnbcs-coverage.html

Comment: Why do you need the exact time the shares start trading?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at historical data for the day in question you can see when holders of shares issued in the IPO began selling them to members of the public (the time of the first “print” or trade)

Note: there are two different events:

1. People who “bought in” to the IPO (“primary” shareholders) were given their shares, and:
2. When primary shareholders sold their shares on the stock exchange (“the secondary market”) to members of the public (who were not allocated shares in the IPO).  The first one of these is the first “print”